# PHP MYSQL str_to_date issue

Tags: php, mysql, database

I cant seem to use str_to_date correctly. Im trying this:

```
$test = "Fri May 01 2015 00:00:00";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ax_timestamps WHERE str_to_date('$test', '%D %M %d %Y %H:%i:%s') < datetimefeild ORDER BY id ASC";
```

But its not pulling the data from the database that it should.

For example the database has a datetime field with this value which should have been pulled:

```
2015-05-16 07:44:56
```

Comment: (1) What is the problem you are encountering?  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.  (2) Do you really have a column with the name "datetimefeild" (misspelt)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what is mean of 'misspelt' ?

Comment: @Fatemeh . . . It is a somewhat old way to write "misspelled", meaning that the word is not spelled correctly.  (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misspelt).

Comment: @GordonLinoff aha i see :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff may I have your email? I always liked to know more about who have more than 10k reputation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the %D value it didnt like for some reason, After pruning it everything worked as expected.

```
$test = "May 01 2015 00:00:00";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ax_timestamps WHERE str_to_date('$test', '%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s') < datetimefeild ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Comment: "Some reason" is that `%D` is the day with english suffix (1st, 2nd etc.), which doesn't match your date format. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ax_timestamps` WHERE str_to_date($test, '%D %M %d %Y %H:%i:%s') < `datetimefeild` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
```

Comment: No it still doesnt return any results even though the sample string is < the datetime in the database field.